# Can't Get CSV Columns to Print Properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, formatting

I'm new to programming and trying to supplement my learning by doing some online tutorials.  Today, I started looking at working with CSV files using a [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-csv-files-python/) that seemed easy enough to follow, but I've ran into what amounts to an immaterial problem, but it's frustrating me that I can't figure it out, haha.  I've spent around two hours Googling and testing things, but I'm just not savvy enough to know what to try next.  Help, please! haha.

Here's the code in question:

```
# importing the csv module
import csv
# csv filename

filename = r'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\AAPL.csv'

# initialize the titles and row list
fields = []
rows = []

# read the csv file
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    # create the csv reader object
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # extract field names through the first row
    fields = next(csvreader)

    # extract each data row one by one
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)

    # get total number of rows
    print("total no. of rows: %d"%(csvreader.line_num))

# print the field names
print("Field names are: " + ", ".join(field for field in fields))

# print the first 5 rows of data
print("\nFirst 5 rows are:\n")
for row in rows[:5]:
    #parse each column of a row
    for col in row:
       print("%10s"%col),
    print("\n")
```

The tutorial was actually written for Python 2.X, so the I found the updated formatting for 3.6 and changed that last statement to be:

```
for col in row:
   print('{:>10}'.format(col))
print("\n")
```

Either way it's written, the results come out in this format:

```
First 5 rows are:

2013-09-18
 66.168571
 66.621429
 65.808571
 66.382858
 60.492519
 114215500
...
```

instead of the expected columnar format shown on the tutorial.

I thought I finally found the solution when I read somewhere that you needed the formatting for each item, so I tried:

```
for col in row:
   print('{:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10}'.format(*col))
print("\n")
```

so that the formatting was there for each column, however that seems to create a column for each letter in the field, e.g:

```
 2          0          1          3          -          0          9
```

The CSV is just a file of AAPLs stock prices--here's the first 9 rows of data if you want to create a CSV for testing:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2013-09-18,66.168571,66.621429,65.808571,66.382858,60.492519,114215500
2013-09-19,67.242859,67.975716,67.035713,67.471428,61.484497,101135300
2013-09-20,68.285713,68.364288,66.571426,66.772858,60.847912,174825700
2013-09-23,70.871429,70.987144,68.942856,70.091431,63.872025,190526700
2013-09-24,70.697144,70.781425,69.688568,69.871429,63.671543,91086100
2013-09-25,69.885712,69.948570,68.775711,68.790001,62.686062,79239300
2013-09-26,69.428574,69.794289,69.128571,69.459999,63.296616,59305400
2013-09-27,69.111427,69.238571,68.674286,68.964287,62.844891,57010100
2013-09-30,68.178574,68.808571,67.772858,68.107140,62.063782,65039100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krishnaa208's answer didn't quite give me the right format.  `print("%10s"%col,end=',')` gave a table that included the comma and each field was surrounded by quotes.  But it did point me in the right direction, which was:

```
# print the first 5 rows of data
print("\nFirst 5 rows are:\n")
for row in rows[:5]:
    #parse each column of a row
    for col in row:
       print('{:>12}'.format(col), end = '')
    print("\n")
```

and my results were:

```
First 5 rows are:

  2013-09-18   66.168571   66.621429   65.808571   66.382858   60.492519   114215500

  2013-09-19   67.242859   67.975716   67.035713   67.471428   61.484497   101135300

  2013-09-20   68.285713   68.364288   66.571426   66.772858   60.847912   174825700

  2013-09-23   70.871429   70.987144   68.942856   70.091431   63.872025   190526700

  2013-09-24   70.697144   70.781425   69.688568   69.871429   63.671543    91086100
```

`{:>10}` was a little to close together since my CSV had the prices down to six decimal points.)

Thanks for the answer, though.  I really did help!

Answer (score 2):

```
# importing csv module 
import csv 

# csv file name 
filename =  r'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\AAPL.csv'


# initialize the titles and row list
fields = []
rows = []

# read the csv file
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    # create the csv reader object
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # extract field names through the first row
    fields = next(csvreader)

    # extract each data row one by one
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)

    # get total number of rows
    print("total no. of rows: %d"%(csvreader.line_num))

# print the field names
print("Field names are: " + ", ".join(field for field in fields))

# print the first 5 rows of data
print("\nFirst 5 rows are:\n")
for row in rows[:5]:
    #parse each column of a row
    for col in row:
       print("%10s"%col,end=',')
    print("\n")
```

You need to replace 
  `print("%10s"%col),` with `print("%10s"%col,end=',')`